# Java awt/swing AffineTransformation to move around shapes

Tags: java, swing, awt, affinetransform

A program that animates circles is not drawing them fluidly once several hundred are drawn at once. It was suggested to use affine transformation to copy the shapes. This code, refactored to use graphics2D, works, but doesn't cause any performance boost since it is still filling hundreds of ovals. How to use affinetransformation properly to fill a shape once and then copy/move it?

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
```

```
    for (int i = 0; i < gameLogic.getParticleArrSize(); i++) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Color color = new Color(6,6,6);
        Ellipse2D oval = new Ellipse2D.Double(
                gameLogic.getParticleXCoor(i),
                gameLogic.getParticleYCoor(i),
                gameLogic.getParticleSize(i),
                gameLogic.getParticleSize(i));
        g2.setPaint(color);
        g2.fill(oval);
        g2.translate(15, 15);
        g2.fill(oval);
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to know which is faster is to profile two or more implementations. As a concrete example, this [kinetic model](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel) shows a slight advantage for *Gradient* mode, using `drawImage()`, over *Color* mode, using `fill()`, as seen in the [`paintComponent()`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel/code#DisplayPanel) method of `DisplayPanel`. In this context, `AffineTransform` is beneficial in pre-rendering the more complex gradient image.

Addendum:

> I don't know how to properly implement `AffineTransform` to move/copy ovals…

I doubt that `AffineTransform` is the cure. Instead, move the object creation out of the loop, as @camickr suggests. In the [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel), note how an `Ensemble` only needs one `Ellipse2D`; it uses `setFrame()` repeatedly. Also, each `Particle` already *knows* its `Color`. Finally, observe how the [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel) measures paint time.

Comment: I don't know how to properly implement affinetransform to move/copy ovals and there is a lack of resources explaining it.

Comment: @comp sci balla: For reference, I've used this related example to handle thousands of nodes:  https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel

Answer (score 1):

Doubt it will make a big difference but:

1. There is no need to create new Color objects inside the loop
2. Instead of keeping multiple arrays of x, y, width, height values keep an ArrayList of Ellipse2D object so you don't have to keep recreating those objects either.

I've also seen an example that uses 5000 balls without a problem. It uses the fillOval(...) method. Don't know if that will make a difference.